# requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'channel_url': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://channel_url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to check the latest video of the Youtube channels given from a CSV file and retrieve the description.

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR : requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'channel_url': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://channel_url?
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

with open('motovloggers.csv', 'r') as data_csv:
    data = csv.reader(data_csv)

    for channel in data:    
        url = channel[2]

        r = requests.get(url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.select_one('.yt-lockup-title a')['title'])
        link = (soup.select_one('.yt-lockup-title a')['href'])

        # # new_link = link.replace('watch?v=', 'embed/')

        print('https://www.youtube.com' + link)

        # video = pafy.new(url)
        # print(video.description)
```

How can it be resolved?

Comment: after url = channel[2] add the statement print(url) and let us know what the output is. The program is complaining about a bad url but as the url is in your csv file we can't see it.

Comment: Getting all the url listed in csv file, but getting the column name too `channel_url
https://www.youtube.com/user/FortyFourTeeth/videos
https://www.youtube.com/user/6Foot4Honda/videos
https://www.youtube.com/user/AdjrianNickelodeon/videos
https://www.youtube.com/user/advancedbiker/videos
https://www.youtube.com/user/bakerXderek/videos
https://www.youtube.com/user/BaronVonGrumble/videos`

Comment: I don't see what you mean by channel_url, but if you could add the exact output (at least a few lines) to you post with proper formatting I might be able to suggest a way of separating it from the rest of the text. I can't tell from what you have provided.

Comment: channel_url
https://www.youtube.com/user/FortyFourTeeth/videos  
https://www.youtube.com/user/6Foot4Honda/videos  
https://www.youtube.com/user/AdjrianNickelodeon/videos  
https://www.youtube.com/user/advancedbiker/videos  
https://www.youtube.com/user/bakerXderek/videos  
https://www.youtube.com/user/BaronVonGrumble/videos  
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCm5PR071dIb_Vj4ujmGA3ow/videos

Comment: I am getting above output, each on a separate line. @Deepstop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are saying you just need to skip the first element of data. So the easiest thing might be to just check it for the string 'channel_url'

```
with open('motovloggers.csv', 'r') as data_csv:
    for channel in csv.reader(data_csv):
        url = channel[2]
        if 'channel_url' in url:
            continue
```

or you could check for https: in the line and continue if it doesn't appear.

Comment: No, it includes channel_url as first line and I think this is the problem. I am sharing output through gist https://gist.github.com/babayagaPy/6b6c6ff47c6f49a634a22f3dcf31b62f @Deepstop

Comment: Understand now. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `channel_url` is a caption of a column in your `csv` file.

So skipping the first line of your file will probably solve the problem:

```py
...
with open('motovloggers.csv', 'r') as data_csv:
    data = csv.reader(data_csv)

    next(data, None)  # <---- skip the first row

    for channel in data:
        ...
```

Comment: TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable
@ivan-vinogradov